# Kernel of homomorphism in Zassenhaus/Butterfly lemma

Tags: group-theory

I was reading the proof of Zassenhaus Lemma in my textbook "Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra by Malik, Moderson, Sen". The lemma states that:

> Let $ H',H,K',K $ be subgroups of group $G$ such that $H'$ is normal
>   in $H$ and $K'$ is normal in $K$.Then $H'(H\cap K')$ is normal in
>   $H'(H\cap K)$ and $(H'\cap K)K'$ is normal in  $(H\cap K)K'$. Furthermore, $${H'(H\cap K)\over H'(H \cap K')} \cong {(H\cap K)K'\over (H'\cap K)K'}$$

The proof considers a homomorphism:
$$f: H'(H\cap K) \to {(H\cap K)\over (H\cap K')(H'\cap K)} $$
We need to show that the kernel of homoorphism $f$ is $H'(H \cap K').
$ Further using the First isomorphism theorem the lemma can be proved conveniently but only once we can obtain the kernel of $f$. 
I am not able to obtain this. Please help me to proceed.

**UPDATE:**
I got a way to somewhat proceed with this. It goes like:

If we consider $a=h'x\in Ker(f)$ where $h'\in H',x\in (H\cap K)$ => $x\in J$
where $J=(H\cap K')(H'\cap K)$. Thus, $x=pq$ where $p\in (H\cap K') ,q\in (H'\cap K) \subset H' $.

> Hence, $a=h'x=h'pq=(h'q)p\in  H'(H \cap K')$

Any better explanation for the above portion please?